# Container::getInstance() returns null

Tags: laravel, containers

I have a line in the code:

```
app(User::class)::unguard();
```

in my tests but the code return an exception:

```
Error: Call to a member function make() on null
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:105
```

so I checked that helper that looks like that:

```
function app($make = null, $parameters = [])
    {
        if (is_null($make)) {
            return Container::getInstance();
        }

        return Container::getInstance()->make($make, $parameters);
    }
```

I am kind of a beginner so I do not really understand laravel in depth yet. The thing I tried was I inserted a code to the app() function like so:

```
function app($make = null, $parameters = [])
    {
        if (is_null($make)) {
            return Container::getInstance();
        }
        dd(Container::getInstance());
        return Container::getInstance()->make($make, $parameters);
    }
```

And I got `null`. I do not really know exactly, how does these thing work. What might be an issue, please?

EDIT: The issue is only appearing in phpunit tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to instantiate class to call static function on it? Shouldn't it work like `User::unguard()`?

Comment: well yeah, you are right. I believe it was not the best example I could have shown. The thing is I need to resolve the problem why I get null when typing 
`dd(Container::getInstance());`
or even when just typing `dd(app())` wherever in my phpunit tests

Comment: The reason might be that you are not properly bootstraping laravel application in your tests. I believe in laravel 5.5 test suite it is done as such `$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`.

Comment: actually, I am using version of Laravel 5.2